# Find the number of recipes possible from given ingredients? SQL Query

Tags: sql, database, h2

I'm struggling to figure out the query (drawing a blank really) to get all recipes that can be created from the stock of ingredients available.

Tables that are created are:

```sql
CREATE TABLE recipe(id int, name varchar(25));  
CREATE TABLE ingredients(id int, name varchar(25), stock int);
CREATE TABLE recipeingredients(recipe_id int, ingredients.id int, amount int);
```

Records in the database would be something like this

```
Recipe
ID | Name        |
1  | Brown Bread |
2  | White Bread |

Ingredients
ID | Name        | Stock |
1  | White Flour | 2     |
2  | Wheat Flour | 1     |
3  | Yeast       | 17    |
4  | Water       | 12    |

RecipeIngredients
RecipeID | IngredientID | Amount |
1        | 1            | 1      |
1        | 3            | 4      |
1        | 4            | 8      |
2        | 2            | 1      |
2        | 3            | 4      |
2        | 4            | 8      |
```

So the result would be something like this

```
Name        | Count |
White Bread | 1     |
Wheat Bread | 1     |
```

This might be something simple but am very rusty at SQL now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select recipe
, min([count]) as 'count'

from (
    select r.name as recipe
    , i.name as ingredient
    , i.stock / ri.amount as 'count'

    from recipeingredients ri
      inner join ingredients i on i.id = ri.ingredients_id
      inner join recipe r on r.id = ri.recipe_id
) q

group by recipe
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. Just getting a syntax error around line 3 that am not sure how to fix.
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: '[count]) as 'count' from ( select r.name as recipe as' at line 3"

Comment: Ah, I found what the syntax issue was. The quotes around 'count' were not liked by h2. Thanks this works great.